# Gridview rowupdating doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

i have a simple task of updating row, on a click of update linkbutton, as

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
            OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" DataKeyNames="ID">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mobile">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("Mobile") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LName">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("LName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<% #Eval("LName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="action">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Edit">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server">Update</asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

at CS page

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox t1 = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;


            string s = t1.Text.ToString();
            Label3.Text = s;
}
```

I tried working on this several times but i don't get any answer. what possible code i am missing or there is any error in a code.Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LinkButton needs to have a CommandName applied to it in the EditTemplate:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandName="Update">Update</asp:LinkButton>
```